Power BI clustered column chart - each column with different filters
I need to create a clustered column chart referencing one table. Each of the two columns I want to show have to be filtered differently to show their data. If I put a filter in the visual it will apply it to both columns which I don't want. How do it do this?
I have tried to create calculated columns using if(and) for each column value and it calculates correctly in the table. When I pull it into the visual, I can't get the SUM aggregator, which I need.

Did you try creating measures, and ignoring the filters you do not want to apply for each calculation.
